# How to access camera view as an image without taking screenshot in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I know I can take screenshots using following:

```
GetWorld()->GetGameViewport()->Viewport->TakeHighResScreenShot();
```

It saves a screenshot in `<Project>\Saved\Screenshots\Windows`. But I want more control over the image. Is it possible, say, to access individual pixels?

Is it possible to get what's on the screen as an image object (and maybe also save it in a custom location)?

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/how-to-access-camera-view-as-an-image-without-taking-screenshot-in-unreal-engine/431744

Seems like people over at [Answers@UnrealEngine](https://answers.unrealengine.com/) are more active.